# Hydrolysis of vinyl silanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Alkynyl silanes can be easily hydrolyzed with TBAF like in the last step in the synthesis:
[image]

How feasible is the hydrolysis of vinyl silanes with TBAF? Does it actually happen or some other routine must be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [This](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2000/P1/B006049F) article, vinylsilanes are stable in TBAF solutions, allowing other silyl groups to be removed selectively. They can be activated in the presence of TBAF using palladium similarly to a halide, though.

[This](http://pubs.rsc.org/en/Content/ArticleLanding/2000/P1/B006049F) link shows C2-trialkylsilylalkenes being cleaved with potassium *t*-butoxide, 16-crown-8 and TBAF. I'll look more thoroughly when I get to a computer, though.

I also found this example, but it had no reference, so I'll try to find one:

[image: Example of protodesilylation of an alkene]

Comment: How to remove the silyl group?

Comment: Oh, you wanted a method to do it, too? That I'm not sure about. Looking at references, it doesn't look simple. See edit made.

Comment: Interesting. Strong bases and mild acids can cleave them.

Comment: What search engine did you use? I couldn't find this.

Comment: I can't find it either, by using Google, I found the [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z7D0CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=selective+protodesilylation+of+terminal+trimethylsilyl&source=bl&ots=a0wtclKA6A&sig=X5LWP0Lj6P82eWX-zKNRRD8JSjc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj855CGmebKAhXB4D4KHZ6aBiwQ6AEICjAA#v=onepage&q=selective%20protodesilylation%20of%20terminal%20trimethylsilyl&f=false).

Comment: Ah, ok. It's a good one.